# .Net Core Project in Team Build / MSBuild?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We are trying to build a .Net Core project in TFS team build. We have VS 2015, Preview Tools 2 and .Net Core 1.1 on the build machine.

From within Visual Studio on that machine, it builds fine.

If we go into the project directory and run dotnet-publish from the command line, it works fine.

From within team build, we get the dreaded dotnet props can't be found error.

I am using global.json in my project.

Any trick to getting team build to work?

Comment: Which build are you using XAML build or vNext build?

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use  [Command line](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line) task in your build definition. First restore Nuget Package with

> **Build your ASP.NET Core project and publish the output to a folder.**
>
> - Tool: `dotnet`
> - Arguments: `publish -c $(BuildConfiguration) -o    $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`
> - Advanced, Working folder: Folder in which the project.json file (for    projects created with VS 2015) or .csproj file (for projects
>     created    with VS 2017) exists.

More details please refer this similar tutorial [Build your ASP.NET Core app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core). Also take a look at this similar question: [Visual studio team services build .net core 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674009/visual-studio-team-services-build-net-core-1-1)

Comment: Is it possible to build a solution with 2 core projects? One dependent on another