# Dotnet restore MyProj.csproj thows "The file type is not recognised" on VSTS

Tags: .net, build, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I'm making my build pipeline for dotnet Core project. Part of my build script executes `dotnet restore`. I do it this way:

```
dotnet restore C:/Projects/MyProj/src/MyProj/MyProj.csproj
```

And it restores locally without a problem. When I push the same script to VSTS build server, in logs I see execution like this:

```
dotnet restore D:/a/1/s/src/MyProj/MyProj.csproj
```

but then I get error:

> error: Invalid input 'D:/a/1/s/src/MyProj/MyProj.csproj'. The file type was not recognized.

What am I doing wrong? why does it work locally and not on VSTS.

I'm using the same version of dotnet.exe locally as on VSTS:

> Version  : 1.1.0
>   Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86

I've got a `global.json` file sitting outside of `src` folder:

```
{
  "projects": ["src"],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.1.0"
  },
  "packages": "packages"
}
```

Folder structure as following:

```
   Root/
       build.cake
       build.ps1
       global.json
       src/
          MyProj.sln
          MyProj/
            MyProj.csproj
            *.cs
          MyProj.Tests/
            MyProj.Tests.csproj
            *.cs
```

Solution is created in VS2017, so this is latest csproj file format.

What else should I check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the project uses VS 2017 and the "released" .NET CLI tooling, you also need to use the `Hosted VS2017` agent queue for the build so that the build will be run on an agent that has the necessary tools installed.

The version of the shared runtime host (`dotnet.exe`) is the same, the difference is that a newer CLI needs to be installed as well (which is in the `sdk` subdirectory of the directory where `dotnet.exe` is).

Comment: I would imagine this thing would be already installed on the build agent... but let me try it

Comment: Yep, I should've realised that installed SDK is not the same as what I'm compiling into. As soon as I installed SDK, I got results. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is correct, but as someone new to VSTS, I wasn't sure what to do. This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42969311/345179