# How to build ASP.NET Core 2 app in TFS

Tags: asp.net, tfs

I'm trying to create a build definition for my ASP.NET Core 2 app in TFS to no avail. As per the documentation (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core), there should be a template named **ASP.NET Core (PREVIEW)** in TFS but I can't seem to find one. I installed VS 2017 Enterprise on the TFS server and choose ASP.Net development components while installing but the template didn't show up. What am I missing here?

Comment: in your task catlog you need to find the .Net Core Preview and add it to ur project

Comment: Yes and that's the problem I mentioned in my question. It's not there.

Comment: show us screeshot , how ur page appears to be

Comment: @Webruster Here it is. No ASP.Net Core Task in this window. https://snag.gy/R7AeWh.jpg

Comment: have you gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674009/visual-studio-team-services-build-net-core-1-1)

Comment: I guess that doesn't apply. The link in my question shows the ASP.Net Core (PREVIEW) option clearly which I can't find anywhere.

Comment: this might be a dumb question --> , are you opening in the web browser ? because i could see that option while opening in web-browser

Comment: Yes, I'm opening in the browser :-)

Comment: weird , i can see that option when i opened in  my browser... your screenshot is showing like it was taken from windows..

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit What's the exact version of TFS do you use? The template added in TFS 2017 update1 and later version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the version of TFS, see [What version of Team Foundation Server do I have?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/)

Based on my test, the template **ASP.NET Core (PREVIEW)** shown in TFS 2017 update1 and later version. If your TFS is the early version, you can upgrade it to the TFS 2017 update1 or later version. You can get TFS from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).

Or you can add the following tasks directly with empty template and set the arguments accordingly based on this article:[Build your ASP.NET Core app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/ci/build-aspnet-core#add-build-tasks):

```
Utility: Command Line
Build: Visual Studio Build
Utility: Command Line
Test: Visual Studio Test
Utility: Archive Files
Utility: Publish Build Artifacts
```

Comment: After updating TFS, I could finally see the ASP.NET Core option. Thank you :-)